# One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am facing some issue on SharePoint list due to some column, named "Name" and detail issue is described on below link,

[image]

[Please click here and review the issue in detail](http://www.docdroid.net/file/view/n3o4/sharepoint-error.pdf)

Kindly check and let me know how to rectify the issues.

Comment: Since there is not much data in your list, the easiest option is to delete the list and create a new one.

Comment: did you try to delete that column?

Comment: I deleted, then I got the above error while deleting list data

Comment: can you check the logs. It can also an issue with lookup column or site column